# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 dual boot Problems?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, uefi

How do I get drivers for my Compaq CQ45 laptop, I need lan drivers and i have already fixed wifi on both partitions. Also how do I get the options to select ubuntu and W7, it automatically boots to windows 7, but if I pause startup i can get to it. (Is UEFI enabled and i did wipe Windows 8). (Wifi card is a Ralink RT5390 but I dont know what Lan port it is)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Fix the LAN driver in Window 7

Download your Ethernet LAN driver for Compaq  http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp45001-45500/sp45181.exe 
Even you can download other drivers for Compaq CQ45 at [Download Site](http://download-laptop-driver.blogspot.in/2013/06/compaq-presario-cq45-windows-7-drivers.html)!

Step 2: Fix the grub error

Fix the grub by following the detailed steps given in the following link.
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: The Lan fix didnt work for some reason it installed but when i go into drivers my lan controller still isnt fixed

Comment: The reason might be either you might have installed the wrong driver or there might be hardware failure with your ethernet card.To fix the wrong driver, goto control panel and remove the LAN driver that you have already installed and try installing the correct one. For checking whether the Ethernet card is working properly, fix the grub, logon to ubuntu and check whether LAN is working.

Comment: The lan still isnt working on both os'.

Comment: Also i cant adjust my brightness on windows

Comment: It tries to but just comes up connecting, disconnected, connecting, disconnected etc...

Comment: Definitely the problem is with your LAN port (or LAN cable). Try pushing the LAN cable into the port more firmly. Confirm whether all the pins in the LAN cable touches the pins in LAN port properly. If you see connecting / disconnecting it means that your driver is working perfect. The problem is only with your LAN port.